# How can I calculate inductance in this page?

Tags: inductor

I have an inductor ring from Micrometals. [T60-26](http://www.micrometals.com/pcparts/torcore2.html)

In this page what is Relative magnetic permeability? [link](http://coil32.net/online-calculators/ferrite-torroid-calculator.html)

For my example is it 50.0?

Answer (score 1):

No - that is not the relative permeability.

They already calculated the effect of the permeability and the magnetic path of the core into a more useful number: \$A_L\$.  This is the inductance in nano-henries that a given number of wire turns on the core will give. The inductance goes up as the square of the number of turns because of mutual inductance between the turns.

For example if you put 10 turns on the core, this will give 10² * 50 = 5000nH.

[A description of \$A_L\$ is here](http://www.encyclopedia-magnetica.com/doku.php/al_value).

Comment: If I want 470uH (microHenry) with T60-26 how can I calcutate the number of turns?

Comment: $$N = \sqrt{\frac{L}{AL}} = \sqrt{\frac{470 \mu H}{50nH/N^2}} = 97 turns$$

Comment: How did you get that result? I got 3.06

Comment: AL is in nano Henry so \$ 470µH = 470000nH\$---> \$470000nH/50nH = 470000/50 = 9400\$ and finally \$ \sqrt{9400} = 96.953 = 97\$

Comment: Oh, yes, I see it now, thank you. 
If you want, write it a new answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Don't bother, I don't help for points.

Comment: @G36 having an accepted answer that's correct isn't for you (the answerer), it's for anyone else that comes across the question.